# How to implement a smooth transition when new bands are created in d3?

Tags: d3.js

In the example below, I'm trying to animate new items appearance.

As you can see, they animate from the bottom of the chart to their position.

However, existing items ("second" in this example) jump, instead of smoothly transitioning to their new position.

I thought it is because the new band suddenly appears, without a transition. So, I tried to add a transition:

```
const band = bandUpdate.enter()
  .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'band')
  .merge(bandUpdate)
    .transition(t)
    .attr('transform', (_, i) => `translate(0, ${i * bandHeight})`);
```

But, I'm getting:

> Uncaught TypeError: band.selectAll(...).data is not a function

Could you explain the error please, and suggest a way to avoid the undesired jump?

**Bonus:** How could I animate the y axis labels?

[Playground](http://codepen.io/moroshko/pen/Ndjebo?editors=0010)

```js
const width = 300;
const height = 200;
const margin = { top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 50 };

let data = {};

const main = d3.select('.chart')
  .append('svg')
    .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);

const xScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 16]).range([0, width]);
const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);

main.append('g')
  .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height})`)
  .call(xAxis);

const yScale = d3.scaleBand().domain([]).range([0, height]);
const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);
const yAxisG = main.append('g').call(yAxis);

const bandG = main.append('g');

function update() {
  const t = d3.transition().duration(500);
  const ids = Object.keys(data);
  
  yScale.domain(ids);
  yAxisG.call(yAxis);
  
  const bandHeight = yScale.bandwidth();
  const bandUpdate = bandG.selectAll('.band').data(ids, id => id);
  const band = bandUpdate.enter()
    .append('g')
      .attr('class', 'band')
    .merge(bandUpdate)
      // .transition(t) // Throws: Uncaught TypeError: band.selectAll(...).data is not a function
      .attr('transform', (_, i) => `translate(0, ${i * bandHeight})`);

  bandUpdate.exit().remove();
  
  const itemUpdate = band.selectAll('.item')
    .data(id => data[id], item => item.value);
  
  const itemG = itemUpdate.enter().append('g').attr('class', 'item');
  const rectHeight = 4;
  
  itemG
    .append('rect')
    .attr('class', (_, i) => `item-${i}`)
    .attr('x', d => xScale(d.value))
    .attr('width', d => width - xScale(d.value))
    .attr('height', rectHeight)
    .attr('y', height)
    .transition(t)
    .attr('y', bandHeight / 2 - rectHeight / 2);

  itemG
    .append('circle')
    .attr('class', (_, i) => `item-${i}`)
    .attr('cx', d => xScale(d.value))
    .attr('r', 6)
    .attr('cy', height)
    .transition(t)
    .attr('cy', bandHeight / 2);
  
  itemUpdate
    .select('rect')
    .attr('x', d => xScale(d.value))
    .attr('width', d => width - xScale(d.value))
    .transition(t)
    .attr('y', bandHeight / 2 - rectHeight / 2);    
  
  itemUpdate
    .select('circle')
    .attr('cx', d => xScale(d.value))
    .transition(t)
    .attr('cy', bandHeight / 2);
  
  itemUpdate.exit().remove();
}

update();

setTimeout(() => {
  data['first'] = [
    {
      value: 7
    },
    {
      value: 10
    }
  ];
  
  update();
}, 1000);

setTimeout(() => {
  data['second'] = [
    {
      value: 1
    }
  ];
  
  update();
}, 2000);

setTimeout(() => {
  data['third'] = [
    {
      value: 13
    }
  ];
  
  update();
}, 3000);
```

```css
svg {
  margin: 0 30px 30px 30px;
}

.item-0 {
  fill: red;
}

.item-1 {
  fill: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="chart"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3@4.4.1/build/d3.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just break your `band` constant:

```
const band = bandUpdate.enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'band')
    .merge(bandUpdate);

band.transition(t)
    .attr('transform', (_, i) => `translate(0, ${i * bandHeight})`);
```

Here is the updated CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oBWJdp?editors=0010

Explanation:

According to the documentation, [selection.transition([name])](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition#selection_transition):

> Returns a new transition on the given selection with the specified name.

So, when you later in the code do this:

```
const itemUpdate = band.selectAll('.item')
    .data(id => data[id], item => item.value);
```

You're selecting a new transition, and that's giving you the error (you cannot bind data to a transition).

Breaking the `band` constant makes `itemUpdate` a selection based in the `band` selection, not in the following transition.

Comment: Oh, wow! This is very surprising. Could you explain why this is **not** equivalent to what I did?

Comment: I guess it's because `.transition()` returns a transition, not a selection, and I assume later in the code (`band.selectAll('.item').data(...)`) that `band` is a selection.

Comment: @MishaMoroshko Yes, that's the reason. You can see that, if you remove `itemUpdate` and `itemG`, you don't get the error anymore.